# powerline-tmux breaks on fedora25

Tags: terminal, fedora, tmux, powerline-networking

I'm using powerline with tmux but it displays multiple status lines and the terminal renders in a mess. 
It's like the screenshot in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606489/zsh-tmux-powerline-multiple-lines-normal-operation

Is there anyone else also seeing this issue? Any suggestion to fix?